# using svg file to public folder vs. as component in nextjs

Tags: javascript, image, svg, next.js, public

I need to use icons that are the same shape and have different sizes and colors.

At first, I was using a different file in the public folder.

ex) public/same-icon_red.svg, public/same-icon_blue.svg

But I think it's better to use it this way than this

```
//icon.js

export const Icon = ({fill, width, height}) => {
  return (
    <svg height={height} width={width} fill={fill} viewBox="0 0 24     24">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24.../>
  </svg>
 );
}
```

```
//main.js

import Icon from "./icon"

...
return(
 <>
  ...
  <Icon width={24} height={24} fill={#000}/>
 </>  
)
```

But in this case, it bothers me that I don't use the public folder.

Which would be the best choice between the two?

Comment: Not sure it matters a whole lot. I've always been a fan of making components out of icons. I feel like they are more flexible. However, you might consider doing something like [this](https://github.com/sdras/vue-sample-svg-icons). I know it's Vue, but it should be easy enough to port.

Comment: Or **Web Component** https://iconmeister.github.io/ which can set all properties (size, color, fill etc.) with HTML attributes or properties, or CSS properties.